# Xamarin UWP HTTPS REST call returns gibberish

Tags: rest, https, uwp, xamarin.forms

It seems I've hit a brick wall here and need new pairs of eyes to see the issue from different angles.

**Context**

I have a Xamarin.Forms PCL application for iOS, Android and UWP.
I need to call REST services; some are plain HTTP and other are HTTPS.

**Issue**

For iOS and Android everything work perfectly fine.
For UWP, HTTP calls work fine, HTTPS calls instead of the expected JSON, return gibberish. This is a sample:

"\u001f�\b\0\0\0\0\0\0��V\nK-*�����W�244��Q\n-N-�K�MU�R*O�+����I�ϪJ,(P�Q\n��\u0001I8��f�)�\u0002\02d+�>\0\0\0"

The code to make the call is in the PCL using the System.Net.Http framework library (see below).

Has anyone encountered a similar issue?

```
        /// <summary>
    /// A generic api call to a REST Web service, with data to be sent.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TParam">The type of object for the data that will be sent, used by post</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TResult">The type of object for the response of the server,expected to be of IClientApiModel type</typeparam>
    ///<param name="Uri">The service URI</param>
    /// <param name="isPost">Whether the API should be treated as POST (<code>true</code>) or as a GET (<code>false</code>).</param>
    /// <param name="param">The input data (can be null).</param>
    /// <param name="authorization">The authorization header for the REST service</param>
    /// <returns>An object of type TResult, and in case of Exception with the HasErrors property set to <code>true</code>.</returns>
    protected async Task<TResult> RequestAsync<TParam, TResult>(string Uri, bool isPost, TParam param, AuthenticationHeaderValue authorization)
        where TResult : IClientApiModel, new()
    {
        try
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(isPost ? HttpMethod.Post : HttpMethod.Get, Uri))
                {
                    request.Headers.Authorization = authorization;

                    if (param != null)
                    {
                        var data = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(param));
                        request.Content = data;
                        request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
                    }

                    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request)) //(request))
                    {
                        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        {
                            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                            {
                                return new TResult() { HasErrors = true, HasNoConnection = true };
                            }
                            return new TResult() { HasErrors = true };
                        }
                        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                        TResult model = content.IsJson() ?
                            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResult>(content) :
                            new TResult() { HasErrors = true };

                        return model;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException weberror)
        {
            throw weberror;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var def = new TResult() { HasErrors = true };
            return def;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you have code in your shared library (PCL) using the HttpClient class to return some kind of data, and in your android and iOS project that data looks correct, but in your uwp applicaiton the returned response is the encoding you listed in your OP above?

Comment: Yes exactly. It also is correct on UWP for HTTP calls. Only UWP+HTTPS seems to be the issue. It should return plain JSON. I also tried to decode (UTF-8) it to no avail.

Comment: do you have this service publicly available to reproduce? If yes please provide uri and authentication

Comment: Hi Yuri. Sorry for the long delay. Unfortunately this is a live service for a client and cannot be accessed for testing purposes. Still haven't found a solution, but a friend pointed me in the direction of possible certificate problem, as it only happens with HTTPS. Still fiddling around...

Answer (score 0):

Just to let everyone know... in the end it all came down to configure a handler for the HttpClient:

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    AllowAutoRedirect = false
};
_httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
```

Comment: Ha... that was only a partial solution. It was tested on a server with only SSL2.0 installed. As soon as it has been moved to the live server with TLS1.2, the good ol' gibberish string is back. Maybe this narrows down the context, yet no solution.